# Why does $p$ have to be moderate in the Poisson approximation to binomial random variable?

Tags: approximation, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

So the proof that a binomial rv with large $n$ approximates a poisson rv with $\lambda = np$ (given below) doesn't seem to use the fact that $p$ is moderate/small, so why does wikipedia and my textbook (Ross) state this as a condition?

Proof:
If $\lambda = np$, then $ P(X = i) = {n \choose i} p^i (1 - p)^{n-i} $
$$ = \frac{(n(n-1) ... (n  - i + 1)}{i!} (\frac{\lambda}{n})^i \frac{(1 - \frac{\lambda}{n})^n}{(1 - \frac{\lambda}{n})^i} $$

and since $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n(n-1) ... (n  - i + 1)}{n^i} = 1$

and $ \lim_{n\to \infty} (1 - \frac{\lambda}{n})^i = 1$

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} P(X = i) = \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}e^{-\lambda}$$

Comment: $(1-\frac \lambda n)^n\approx e^{-\lambda}$ only if $\frac \lambda n=p$ is small. Alternatively, notice that while means of $B(n,p)$ and $Pois(np)$ agree, their variances are $np(1-p)$ and $np$ respectively - which are close only if $p$ is small.

Comment: noting that $np(1 - p)$ and $np$ are close when p is small is a good answer. thank you. i didn't think of that, but i'm still interested in how my argument above relies on the fact that p is small. can you expand on your first statement that $(1-\frac \lambda n)^n\approx e^{-\lambda}$ only if p is small?

Comment: That's equivalent to $1-p\approx e^{-p}$ which holds only for small $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential problem is that if $\lambda = np$, then $\lambda$ is a function of $n$, and if you take the limit as $n \to \infty$, then $\lambda$ will increase without bound unless $p$ is small. Therefore, any time you write $n \to \infty$ while treating $\lambda$ as a constant independent of $n$ in evaluating the limit, you are implicitly stating that $p \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

$$\begin{align*} \Pr[X = i] &= \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} \\ &= \prod_{k=1}^{i} \frac{n+1-k}{k}  \left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^i \frac{(1-\lambda/n)^n}{(1-\lambda/n)^i} \\ &= \frac{\lambda^i}{i!} \prod_{k=1}^i \frac{n+1-k}{n} \frac{(1-\lambda/n)^n}{(1-\lambda/n)^i}. \end{align*}$$  Now if we take the limit, we get $$\begin{align*} \Pr[X = i] &\approx \frac{\lambda^i}{i!} \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^i \left( 1 - \frac{k-1}{n} \right) \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} \right)^n  \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} \right)^i \\ &= \frac{\lambda^i}{i} (1)(e^{-\lambda})(1) \\ &= e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}. \end{align*}$$  But again, this limit treats $\lambda$ as a constant with respect to $n$.

---

An even easier way to see this is to note that $$(1 - p)^n = (1 - \lambda/n)^n$$ if $\lambda = np$.  But if you take the limit of each side with respect to $n$, we find that the LHS tends to $0$ for any $p \in (0,1)$, whereas the RHS tends to $e^{-\lambda}$ if you treat $\lambda$ as a constant with respect to $n$.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. i see now that we are treating λ as a constant w/r to n, which it's not, but I don't see how a moderate p compensates for this. λ=np will increase without bound as n increases even if p is small. and how am i implicitly implying that p approaches anything? your second comment is interesting, but just further confuses me, it seems to imply that treating λ is constant wr to n leads to the wrong answer

Comment: @DavidKatz "p is small", mathematically speaking, means "p goes to zero in some relevant limit". One can then use this approximation when p is fixed--but one should be careful about the error in using it. As it happens, if p is relatively small (say less than 1/8 or so), as n increases you see a "binomial-like" period, a "Poisson-like" period, and eventually a "normal-like" period. If p is too large then you never really see the "Poisson-like" period at all.

Comment: @Ian  How would you differentiate "binomial-like" and "Poisson-like"? To me it looks like for small $p$ ($<0.1$), "Poisson-like" period starts right away (with $n=1$).

Comment: @A.S. Poisson-like in a pmf graph looks like a bump near the mean followed by relatively slow decay to the right. Binomial(30,0.1) is a good example. By contrast binomial(5,0.1) has no bump, it just decreases. (To be fair, you can have a Poisson($\lambda)$ variable for $0<\lambda<1$, but compare Binomial(5,0.1) to Binomial(500,0.001).)

Comment: @Ian But the the ratio of skews of $B(n,p)$ and $Pois(np)$ is independent of $n$ as both are proportional to $n^{-1/2}$. What metric could distinguish proposed binomial-like (say $n=1$) and Poisson-like (say $np=1$) regions? For example we can use skew to distinguish Poisson-like (skew present) and Normal-like regions (negligible skew).

Comment: @A.S. The actual skew as a moment is the same, sure, but the Poisson of course has the larger tail. Still I admit that this is more qualitatively important for larger $\lambda$, since you need larger $\lambda$ to really see the asymmetric unimodal behavior. I'm not sure about a metric, perhaps one could compare characteristic functions?

Comment: @Ian Ratio of characteristic functions is closest to $1$ for $n=1$ since $B(n,p)$ is the sum of $n$ Bernoullis and $Pois(np)$ is the sum of $n$ Poissons. Comparing $B(1,p)$ with $B(n,p/n)$ was the most illuminating in what you meant - but a quantitative metric would be great. I would still consider $\lambda=1$ (or at least $\lambda\le 1$) to be the most *essentially* Poisson as I don't see how having anything to the left of the bump is important. How would you characterize/approximate $P(\lambda)$ for $\lambda\ll 1$? (for $\lambda\gg 1$ we have a normal). As $B(n,\lambda/n)$ for small $n$?

Comment: @Ian You are correct about "Binomial like" region as long as we interpret $P(\lambda)$ for $\lambda\ll 1$ (say $\le 0.1$) to be in the Binomial-like region of $B(n,\lambda/n)$ for $n\in [3,10]$ or even $B(1,\lambda)$. We need to investigate $d_{TV}(B(n,p),P(np))$ as a function of $n$. Chein's bound suggests it's minimized for $n=1$.

Comment: @Ian We can also approximate $P(\lambda)$ for small $\lambda$ as a negative binomial $NB(r,\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+r})$ - even for $r=1$ (that is geometric). In this sense $P(\lambda)$ is *essentially* Poisson (not far from the mean) only when $\lambda$ is on the order of $10^0$.

Comment: @Ian All these approximations are good (as a ratio of probabilities) only a few $\sigma$'s away from the mean (or $1$ unit away if $\sigma$ is small), hence it makes little sense to talk about right tail of $B(30,0.1)$ being Poisson-like just because distribution shapes look similar. In this sense we can say that (for $p^*=\min \{p,1-p\}$) $B(n,p)$ is *Bernoulli*-like for $np^*\ll 1$, Poisson-like for $p^*\ll 1$ and $np^*\approx 1$ and Normal-like for $np^*\gg 1$, and only when $p^*$ is not small and $np^*$ is not large is it essentially binomial.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to approximate $P_i=B_i(n,p)$ for large $n$, small $\alpha=\frac i n$ and small $p$. We'll derive the first correction factor to the $Pois(np)$ approximation $PA_i(\lambda)$.
$$P_i=\binom n i p^i(1-p)^{n-i}=e^{-\lambda}\frac {\lambda^i}{i!}\frac {n_{(i)}}{n^i}\frac {(1-p)^{n(1-\alpha)}}{e^{-np}}\approx PA_i(\lambda)(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac 1{2n})^ie^{n(\alpha p-p^2/2)}=PA_i(\lambda)e^{\alpha/2-n\alpha^2/2+np(\alpha-p/2)}=PA_i(\lambda)e^{\alpha/2-\frac 1 2n(\alpha-p)^2}=PA_i(\lambda)e^{\alpha/2-\frac {(i-\lambda)^2}{2n}}\approx PA_i(\lambda)\exp(\frac 1 2 p(1-\frac{(i-\lambda)^2}{\lambda}+\frac {i-\lambda}{\lambda}))\approx PA_i(\lambda)\exp(\frac 1 2 p(1-\frac{(i-\lambda)^2}{\lambda}))$$

Hence approximation is best when we are one standard deviation away form the mean, underestimates within one std and overestimates outside of one std region - which coincides with the intuition that Poisson is slightly overdispered Binomial - and that it worsens as $p$ increases.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for example that $p=1/2$ and $n$ is say $100$. Let $i=50$. Then $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-i+1)}{n^i}$ is quite far from $1$.  So the *argument* quoted no longer works.

Comment: i'm still not sure i follow. i think the issue in your example is that n is just not big enough for $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-i+1)}{n^i}$ to be close to 1, not that p is not small enough.

Comment: The same issue will occur if $n=1000$, $p=1/2$, and $i=500$.

Comment: But the same will issue will come up for $p=0.01$ if $i/n=1/2$. Poisson is a bad approximation *everywhere* for non-small $p$ (what OP wants) and is a bad approximation for all $p$ if $i/n$ isn't small (what your examples show).